# How to calculate a list with Numpy Array and operators on it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to turn a list into a calculation

Input:

```
arr = ['(', np.array([462., 356., 438., 247., 313., 401., 409., 558., 553., 419.]), '+', np.array([462., 356., 438., 247., 313., 401., 409., 558., 553., 419.]), ')', '**', '2']
```

My expected output is the result of the calculation in the list:

```
[ 853776  506944  244036 391876... ]
```

I tried to find a way to transform everything to string to try to use eval() but it gives me an error because of the Numpy array.

Code:

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import re

tv=TvDatafeed()

def getTVData(instrument, dfeed):
    df = pd.DataFrame(tv.get_hist(instrument, dfeed, Interval.in_monthly, n_bars=10))
    df1 = df[['close']]

    x = df1.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n')
    vals = [float(ele) for ele in x]
    return vals
            
def condition(val):
    gg = val
    gg2 = val

    if ':' in val:
        nobracket = val.replace('(','')
        nobracket2 = nobracket.replace(')','')

        nooperand = re.split(r'[/*+^-]', nobracket2)
        for i, vals in enumerate(nooperand):
            if ':' in vals:
                splitted = vals.split(':')
                TVDataRes = getTVData(splitted[1], splitted[0])
                gg = gg.replace(vals, ''.join(map(str, map(ord, vals))), 1)
                test = re.compile(r'\s*([()+*/^-]|\d+)')
                x = re.findall(test,gg)
                for idx, vals2 in enumerate(x):
                    if ''.join(map(str, map(ord, vals))) in vals2:
                        x[idx] = np.array(TVDataRes)
                        gg2 = x
                        
                    if ('^' in vals2):
                        x[idx] = '**'
                        gg2 = x
        

    else:
        print("Not valid")

for i,val in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
    condition(val)
    break
```

Comment: You list needs 'np.array'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution to achieve what you are trying to do. I changed array() to list() which is the inbuilt python function but for your use case you have to use np.array()

```py
arr = list([462., 356., 438., 247., 313., 401., 409., 558., 553., 419.]), list([462., 356., 438., 247., 313., 401., 409., 558., 553., 419.])
output = []

for i in range(len(arr[0])):
  output.append((int(arr[0][i]) + int(arr[1][i]))**2)

print(output)
```

which returns:

```py
>>> [853776, 506944, 767376, 244036, 391876, 643204, 669124, 1245456, 1223236, 702244]
```

as desired.